# How to make Angular-CLI compile SCSS to CSS and copy it to assets folder

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, sass

I have an Angular 5 project, I have an assets folder and where I place my common CSS file and reference it in index.html, now I am planning to create another folder called "sasstyles" and I will create some .scss file there when I compile or run I want all the .scss file contained on  "sasstyles" folder are compiled as .css and copied to the assets folder. how I do this in angular 5 or later

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='./assets/css/common.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. What I found is the following.
Inside angular.json build options:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    {
        "input": "src/sasstyles/something.scss",
        "inject": false,
        "bundleName": "something"
    }
]
```

That will create a "compiled" something.css file in the root output folder.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to put the result into assets. It seems there used to be a bug acting as a feature that let you specify it like this:

```
"bundleName": "assets/something"
```

But it no longer works (*Edit: I mean the bug/hack to specify subfolder no longer works. The basic solution does work, but puts the resulting css directly under /dist). See here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20360